# Java Application on Smartphone

Tags: java, mobile, smartphone

What alteration should be made in a Java Application to be able to install it on Java Enabled Smartphone?

I tried using a random app of mine to see what happens, when I open it on the cell, it says Install? I say yes, and it says invalid file.

Now I was wondering what alteration should be made?

My smartphone (Samsung S8500) runs on bada which is more or less the same as Android, but alterations in the General.

Comment: you are triying to install a java application or j2me??

Comment: i guess he's referring to Desktop application.

Comment: Don't know actually. Was playing around and because I do designing work, it would be nice to have like a JCoolerChooser Application which I wrote on my phone. Just as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need different SDK for smartphones. Like for Android, you need Android SDK 1.5 or any other version. You just cannot install the same application. You need to develop using the resources provided by the SDK.
If your application is Java based mobile application then you can use some tools to convert it for Android. Doesn't work every time but worth a try.

In your case, Bada OS is not like Android what i learn from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bada). So, you need to develop the application using **J2ME** .